# Find which view is breaking constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am having issues with Auto Layout, getting "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." error.

Now I have added identifiers to all my constraints, however, the conflicting constraints seem not to be created by me since I only see my identifiers in couple of the conflicting constraints.

My question is, if I have such a description of the constraint:

`<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8dca498410 V:[UIView:0x7f8dca493010]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f8dca493610]>`

how can I find out which UIView this is and which UILabel this is. I know I can do `po 0x7f8dca493010`, but how can I print the properties of my view, best would be to print e.g. the name I give to the view in IB?

Comment: Assign accessibilitylabel`s to your Views , then print out it and you can see the label

Comment: Is there something that I can fetch without editing all the views? I have quite a few in there.

Comment: If you know the name of the property you can always do `po [(UIView*)0x7f8dca493010 propertyName]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this command to print all view

```
(lldb) po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

Then command + F to find the address

[image]

Then,with the help of View Debugging left side and the log to locate the View

[image]

**Also,**
If you are familiar with LLDB,you can execute any code you want

```
lldb) e UIView *$view = (UIView *)0x7fb3b248d860
(lldb) po [$view superview]
<UIView: 0x7fb3b248d4e0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb3b248cca0>>
```

Comment: How would this be in Swift? I tried `po UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow().recursiveDescription()`, but I get `error: called object type 'id' is not a function or function pointer`

Comment: I test with a swift project,the command I post works in LLDB. You just need to replace the address with the one you find